# Jupyterlab i18next: How to extract translatable strings from JupyterLab notebooks?

Tags: python, internationalization, jupyter-lab, i18next

I would like to offer my JupyterLab notebooks in several languages (de-de, en-us).

In order to do so, I marked some strings

```
import gettext

domain = 'my_application_name'
localedir = '.'
translate = gettext.translation(domain, localedir, fallback=True)
_ = translate.gettext # using _ as name for the translation function is kind of standard in python
                      # do not confuse with private markers or underscore library
                      # https://github.com/serkanyersen/underscore.py

print(_('Hello World'))

print(_('another translation key'))
```

Then I downloaded **xgettext.exe** for windows from
https://github.com/mlocati/gettext-iconv-windows/releases/download/v0.21-v1.16/gettext0.21-iconv1.16-static-64.zip

and tried to extract the strings with following console command:

```
xgettext.exe my_notebook.ipynb
```

I got the warning

```
xgettext.exe: warning: file 'my_notebook.ipynb' extension 'ipynb' is unknown; will try C
```

and no output file was generated.

**=> What is the recommented way for extracting translatable strings from JupyterLab notebooks?**

I would prefer a solution, where no extra binary (like xgettext.exe) would be required on windows.

Does JupyterLab itself provide some translation features/extension (not for the UI but for notebooks)?

As a possible workaround, the notebook could first be converted to a python file with nbconvert and then passed to xgettext.exe. However, that seems to be too complicated. There should be a more elegant solution.

(The extraction of translatable strings from python files does work on windows, e.g.

```
xgettext.exe my_python_file.py
```

)

The rough **workflow** for translations seems to be:

1. Mark all strings that should be translated
2. Generate a translation file template from the strings (="master list" or Portable Object Template (POT) file)
3. Translate the translation file template
4. Apply the translation file

**Related:**

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/11753
https://docs.python.org/3/library/i18n.html
https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2015/i18n/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the already mentioned workaround based on **nbconvert** and **xgettext**:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script my_notebook.ipynb --output z_temp_file_for_translation
xgettext.exe z_temp_file_for_translation.py -o translations.pot
del z_temp_file_for_translation.py
```

As an alternative to xgettext, the python package **Babel** can be used:

```
pip install Babel
```

Also see: http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/cmdline.html#extract

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script my_notebook.ipynb --output z_temp_file_for_translation
pybabel extract z_temp_file_for_translation.py -o translations.pot
del z_temp_file_for_translation.py
```